# Why is the batch file I created not called?

Tags: windows, batch-file, call

I am making a game and an installer for it in batch. The game has a pause option (input 5), but it doesn't call the `pause.bat` file that I created with the installer.

I made a map for it with 2 submaps in it "map 1" and "map 2" the pause menu and the other menus are located in "map 1" and "map 2" has all the play files in it. I tried a lot but it didn't work.

Here is `C:\.mygame\map2\play.bat`

```
set /p Attack=Choose your attack:
if %Attack%==5 call pause.bat 
if %Attack%==1 call Attack1.bat 
if %Attack%==2 call Attack2.bat 
if %Attack%==3 call Attack3.bat 
if %Attack%==4 call Attack4.bat 
goto NoMana
```

And here is contents of `\map1\pause.bat`

```
:pause
cls
```

Comment: `call C:\mygame\map1\pause.bat`

Comment: `call ..\map1\pause.bat` would be an alternative. It is also not recommended to name a batch-file `pause` as this causes the pause command to not work.

Comment: If this is a game, then perhaps calling a label would be faster? As well, in `pause.bat` the pause command is used as a label, and does not pause as the name suggests it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try avoid overriding of commands when it's possible:

```
if "%Attack%"=="5" call MyPause.bat
```

Because there is a native command `pause`.